# Why my application does not appear in "Google Play Market" of the tablet?

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I just published my application on "Google Play" but I noticed that the application in question appears browsing "Google Play" from smartphones, but does not appear on "Google Play" of my tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1. How come this problem?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:versionCode="32" android:versionName="4.7" 
    package="it.app.my">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application android:debuggable="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">


    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I would assume that the Tab 10.1 does not have vibration and that that permission is causing it to not appear.

Comment: so how can I solve the problem by leaving, however, "android.permission.VIBRATE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead of `uses-permission`:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>
```